# What is the max level in Kingdoms of Amalur?

Tags: kingdoms-of-amalur-reckoning

What is the level cap in Kingdoms of Amalur?

And, perhaps more importantly, how many ability points will you have when you reach it? Is it always 3 per level? Can you get ability points in ways other than leveling up?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The maximum level you can gain is **40**. This gives you **120 maximum ability points** as you get 3 pre-picked ones in the beginning (as pointed out by RavenDreamer) and 3 with each level up.

This can be confirmed by a [hands-on preview](http://nzgamer.com/ps3/previews/1002/kingdoms-of-amalur-reckoning-2nd-hands-on.html) that appeared on NZGamer Feb. 1st.

Also by this image from the in-game manual:

[image]

Comment: I believe you, but do you have a source?

Comment: I'll brb with source and a correction, just found out skill points can be obtained in other ways beside leveling up.

Comment: I think you mean 120 maximum ability points, by the way. You have 3 at level 1 - they're pre-picked, but you do have them.

Comment: Also when you respec at a fateweaver it will remove the three pre-picked out ones so you can place them wherever you like.

Comment: Can you get ability points from any means other than by leveling up?

Comment: @RavenDreamer The in-game manual says level 40 as I recall.

Comment: The information about the maximum level being bored is incorrect. I am currently at level 41. And no longer receive any experience points for the correct answer is 41 not 40.

Comment: I think this is wrong; I'm on level 41.

Comment: It's 123 points. You get 3 at level 0. 
For example. I'm level 1 right now, and I have 6 ability points.

Answer (score 6):

While [Marcelo's answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/49943/what-is-the-max-level-in-kingdoms-of-amalur/49945#49945) does an excellent job of pointing out the maximum level, the lesser half of my question, about the maximum number of ability points, has hereunto remained unanswered.

Strictly speaking, there are many more ways to gain bonus skills than there are to gain bonus abilities (skill books, trainers, etc.).

However, there *are* two ways to acquire more than the 120 ability points you get from level up.

The first is from [epic gems](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/49996/what-epic-gems-exist-in-kingdoms-of-amalur). The Gem of Enlightenment gives up to 15 ability points, and one of the tree specific gems can potentially give up to 25.

The second, is from Purple and Gold armor pieces. Though I don't know what all pieces give the bonus (that is beyond the scope of the question), there are some items, such as the Mercenary's Boots, below, that also give +1 to all abilities in at tree, which means another potential +25.

On the other hand, 120 ability points is already a lot, and you may not wind up interested in half the skills you might be able to unlock (some are even exclusive; chakram and sceptre mastery, for instance). But if you're dead set on maximizing your number of abilities, this'd be the way to do it.

[image]

Comment: FYI, While true, they don't count towards unlocking further in the tree.

Tree unlocks are based on placed skill points.

Answer (score 3):

**Level 40 is the max.**  With the assistance of trainers you can have practically all skills (i.e. lockpicking, etc,...) maxed out.  I currently am only missing 5 more points to max out all of them and I have not finished the game.  In addition, you can't contribute to tier 6 abilities if you do a hybrid UNLESS you only add a very small amount in one class while the majority of ability points are applied to another.  When you visit a fateweaver you WILL NOT be able to reset the skills acquired through trainers or from character selection.  This means if you create a character with +1 skill in lockpicking and a trainer gives you +1 in alchemy you will not get those points back when visiting a fateweaver.  They will stay attached to those skills.

There is a utility gem or epic gem (it escapes me right now exactly which) that will add +1 to all abilities in the first 4 tiers for all classes.  You can smithy a chest armor to include that gem.  There are also accessories that help a great deal.  You will also aquire perm changes to each class (might, finess, sorcery) throughout the game.  You can be 3 or 4 or even 5 over the default max when it comes to an ability.

Answer (score 1):

The manual said the max level is 40, but when you reach level 40 your experience bar continues to go up. I'm currently level 40 with 2272 / 185500 experience

Comment: The same thing is happening to me. I am level 40 but i have a little over 2000 experience towards level 41 but am not getting anymore experience?

Answer (score -3):

Warlord Destiny
Requirements:

Might: 109 (109/3pts = Lvl:36)

- Finesse: 0
- Sorcery: 0

There have been few Warlords in the history of Amalur, and they were all respected and feared as the primal embodiments of conflict itself. This Destiny allows you to endure any and all attacks while laying waste to those who would dare to oppose you.

+30% Melee Attack Damage
 +20% Block Efficacy
 +20% Stun Duration
 +20% Chance to Stun
 Last Stand - Automatically resurrect with 20% Health. Health drains until an enemy is killed.

Tier 6 is the highest you're Destinies go ... so, I would say that level cap aint much higher!

Comment: Welcome to the site! This question already had two detailed answers that said the level cap is 40. Please be sure to take other answers into account before answering yourself. Saying "it's probably not much higher than 36" doesn't add much value.

Answer (score -6):

I have pretty much finished everything one can in the Amalur. I made an archmage build and it was fun. Very very powerful with the area effect magic, weapons come secondary.

And now some corrections that were said above. Yes LV 40 is final and your experience does not go any higher after reaching this point (PC). No matter how many enemies you kill, no more experience points can be earned. You do get fate points but using it doesn't give you experience boost anymore.

I did 212 quests, 11 tasks open and the main questline finished. Maybe a few more quests can be done by finishing some tasks that actually can be finished? I tried to do über weapon with salvaging but it was never better in damage point of view than a staff I got in the end of the game. I sagecrafted a weapon gem with fire damage and got its damage to 207. My sceptre did 145 damage but I didn't use it so much.

My mana never run out with spells anymore except using sceptre in fights. The bad thing with sceptres is no rapid-fire by holding button down and the damage is not area effect. You can, of course, sagecraft mana regen gems and you are good to go but why not just use area effect spells? Much better and faster way to end fights.

Only bugs I noticed were pick-pocketing daggers from ambassador, later killing her and not being able to loot them anymore. The quest didn't check do I have the daggers already. The solution was to sell daggers to a fence and buy back and reach a good ending for the quest. Second bug was House of Ballads suit sticking to my inventory and not being able to sell, remove or add it to junk and destroy. You only need to wear it to enter Windemere the first time. Remove the suit to your personal chest asap or you'll have to carry it with you for the rest of the game. You'll also get much better suits later.

I ended up using spiritweave suit with a lot of slots for sagecrafting gems. Armor strength was 722 but I found a combination to go even over 750. If you make gems with health regen, you're invincible. I decided to make gems with day and night time damage to increase my over all spell damage. This way the game remained even something challenging in the boss fights.

My instructions for a mage build is to increase your spells' damage. Fear Gorta is very good after maxing its upgrades out. It heals you tremendously by hitting the enemies and acting as a tank. Your best damage spell is Meteor so get it as soon as possible. Mark of Flame will keep you alive before that. Also Tempest is very good area effect spell and charges much faster than Meteor. The best spell against Niskarus is Ice Barrage with its upgrade. Remember not to master only one element! By knowing two of them you can survive.

Forget mastering weapons except maybe one, it's just waste of points. Use repair kits and drink healing potions instead of getting the healing spell. Also Elemental Rage is the worst spell ever, they hit you before you can jump away. By increasing Sorcery you boost your spell power. Maximum is 7 of 5 which means in the end only +2 to Sorcery is necessary. Remember to look for lorestones, keep distance to your enemies and use area effect spells!

Comment: How is any part of this after the second paragraph relevant?