# What epic gems exist in Kingdoms of Amalur?

Tags: kingdoms-of-amalur-reckoning

When considering building a character with a high amount of blacksmithing or sagecrafting it would be helpful to know more about the potential benefits of the gems that can be incorporated into equipment.

There are armor, weapon, utility and epic gems.  From the names it's somewhat obvious what they are used for (ok utility isn't necessarily crystal clear).  Epic gems seem to give the best buffs.

What recipes exist to create epic gems and what stats do they give?

Comment: @Sterno When I asked the question I didn't realize the number of permutations that were actually possible so yeah, the scope probably needs some pruning

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The formatting might still be improved, but here's the info dump for ya. These are from Pristine Quality shards.

> Magic+Magic   **Sorcerer's Gem**  +1 all unlocked Sorcery skills
>
> Magic+Lightning   **Gem of Abatement**    -20% Mana Cost
>
> Magic+Fire    **Gem of Abatement**    -20% Mana Cost
>
> Magic+Ice **Gem of Abatement**    -20% Mana Cost
>
> Magic+Physical    **Warrior's Gem**   +1 all unlocked Might skills
>
> Magic+Protection  **Gem of Enlightenment**    +1 to all first four tier skills
>   in all trees
>
> Magic+Poison  **Rogue's Gem** +1 all unlocked Finesse skills
>
> ---
>
> Lightning+Lightning   **Gem of Tempest's Vengence**   75% chance to shock enemies when Attacked
>
> Lightning+Ice **Gem of Magic Resonance**   +20% Lightning, Fire, and Ice
>   damage
>
> Lightning+Physical    **Gem of Opulence**  +20% gold drops
>
> Lightning+Fire    **Gem of Magic Resonance**   +20% Lightning, Fire, and Ice
>   damage
>
> Lightning+Protection  **Gem of the Assiduous**     +8% more experience
>
> Lightning+Poison  **Gem of Unrivaled Vitality**    +50 HP and MP
>
> ---
>
> Ice+Ice   **Gem of Winter's Vengeance**   75% chance to freeze enemies when Attacked
>
> Ice+Physical  **Gem of Opulence**  +20% gold drops
>
> Ice+Fire  **Gem of Magic Resonance**   +20% Lightning, Fire, and Ice damage
>
> Ice+Protection    **Gem of the Assiduous**     +8% more experience
>
> Ice+Poison    **Gem of Unrivaled Vitality**    +50 HP and MP
>
> ---
>
> Physical+Physical **Gem of the Subjugator**    +15% Damage and +10% damage
>   resistance
>
> Physical+Fire **Gem of Opulence**  +20% gold drops
>
> Physical+Protection   **Gem of the Enlightened**   +10% experience
>
> Physical+Poison   **Gem of Opulence**  +20% gold drops
>
> ---
>
> Fire+Fire **Gem of Summer's Vengeance**   75% chance to burn enemies when Attacked
>
> Fire+Protection   **Gem of the Assiduous**     +8% more experience
>
> Fire+Poison   **Gem of Unrivaled Vitality**    +50 HP and MP
>
> ---
>
> Protection+Protection **Gem of Paralyzing Vengeance** 60% chance to stun enemies when Attacked
>
> Protection+Poison **Gem of the Assiduous**     +8% more experience
>
> ---
>
> Poison+Poison **Gem of Plague's Vengeance**   75% chance to poison enemies when Attacked