# What determines the cost to respec?

Tags: kingdoms-of-amalur-reckoning

In Kingdoms of Amalur, you have "Skills" and "Abilities". If you later want to change what you picked, you need to visit a fateweaver to respec. ([This is also how you can pick where the original 3 pre-assigned points go](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/49943/what-is-the-max-level-in-kingdoms-of-amalur#comment73057_49945))

But to actually do this, you need gold. How much gold? Well, it seems to vary. Is it a linear scale with level? Does it go down with time? Does it go up each time you do it? Does it vary with difficulty, perhaps? Does the formula change even between fateweavers, perhaps?

How does the game determine the cost to respec?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Respec costs are tied into your character level and the number of previous respecs you've had. The difficulty level has no effect on the cost.

> Respec cost = 256 * (Character Level) * (# of previous respecs)

In the exceptional case where the number of previous respecs is 0 because you haven't ever respecced before, plug 1 into the formula. Thus, the very first two respecs you do, if you're the same level for both of them, will cost the exact same amount.

I've tried at two different fate weavers, and it didn't affect the formula. The Mercantile skill also had no effect.